# How to generate multiple wrappers for a single C function?

Tags: java, c, swig

I have a C function like so.

```
void useData(char* buf) {
   // TODO.....
}
```

With swig I've managed to get this generated.

```java
public static void useData(SWIGTYPE_p_char buf) {
    // SWIG stuff....
}
```

Now this worked but sometimes I want to pass a `ByteBuffer` instead of `SWIGTYPE_p_char`.
With another typemap, I've managed to generate this.

```java
public static void useData(ByteBuffer buf) {
    // SWIG stuff....
}
```

This works but my new typemap overrides the old typemap and I can't call the function with `SWIGTYPE_p_char` anymore.

My goal is to generate two entry points to my `useData` function, one that takes a `ByteBuffer` and one that takes a `SWIGTYPE_p_char`.

I've been googling and reading through the docs for days now and I can't find anything.

Is this something I can even achieve with SWIG? Or is there something I'm missing? I would highly appreciate pointers, specific docs or alternative search terms.

EDIT:
With the `ByteBuffer` typemap, SWIG only generates `ByteBuffer` but doesn't generate `SWIGTYPE_p_char`. I'm trying to make it generate both.

Comment: *my new typemap overrides the old typemap* - what makes you think that? Java supports overloading, so it is perfectly valid to reuse method names with different arguments.

Comment: Java supports it but SWIG only generates one, using the "latest" typemap.

Answer (score 0):

You can just keep the both generated functions. That's perfectly valid from java side.

Comment: Yes, it's valid from the Java side but SWIG only generates one of them, instead of both.